# How can I encrypt the entire disk on alternate installation?

Tags: installation, encryption, luks

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 11.04 with full disk encryption?

Previously versions have had an alternate install cd with a text interface where you could enable encryption for your drives.
This one is fully graphical and is missing that encryption option.

Comment: **NOTE:** the alternate CD is no longer available since Ubuntu 12.10. From this last release version you can encrypt the entire disk from the normals Live editions (LiveUSB, LiveCD, LiveDVD).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to [releases.ubuntu.com/11.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/) and download the alternate install CD for your architecture.
2. Burn the .iso to a blank CD.
3. Reboot with the CD in the drive, and allow the computer to boot from the CD.
4. On the Ubuntu alternate CD's menu, select "Install":
   [image: Alternate CD's menu]
5. Follow the installer's instructions until you get to the step entitled "Partition Disks".
6. Choose "Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" from the menu. [image: Partition disks menu]
7. Finish the installation by following the instructions on the screen.

Comment: What encryption mechanism (i.e. dm-crypt) does this use?

Comment: It uses dm-crypt for encryption, complying with the LUKS specification, I believe.