# How do I encrypt all my hard disk and not only the home directory

Tags: encryption

How do I encrypt all my hard disk and not only the home directory, so it would ask me for a password when it boots and try to mount the hard disk to start Ubuntu?

I just wanna my system be 100% secure.

Comment: have you read this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/48766/how-can-i-encrypt-the-entire-disk-on-alternate-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform the installation with the alternate CD.

You can then perform installation into an encrypted root partition (LUKS) with or without LVM.

It is easier to use LVM as you can then use LVM to create multiple partitions (/home , swap) , but only enter a password once when you boot.

There is a full graphical walk-through here : http://joernfranz.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/installing-ubuntu-10-10-with-full-disk-encryption/

Would be nice if someone made such a graphical walk through on the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: Yes i know about lvm in fact this was the reason i liked sabayon so much it helps me a lot !